# Lua program error attempt to call field 'getclient' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using the following code to list the clients connected to my ESP8266 access point.

```
cfg={}
cfg.ssid="ESP8266_";
cfg.pwd="12345678"
wifi.ap.config(cfg)
cfg={}
cfg.ip="192.168.1.1";
cfg.netmask="255.255.255.0";
cfg.gateway="192.168.1.1";
wifi.ap.setip(cfg);
wifi.setmode(wifi.SOFTAP)
table={}
table=wifi.ap.getclient()
for mac,ip in pairs(table) do
 print(mac,ip)
end
```

But it's returning me an error:

```
attempt to call field 'getclient' (a nil value)
```

Comment: so the other wifi.ap functions work properly?

Comment: Which firmware do you use? It works for me (only changed SSID and pwd) on a recent build from the `dev` branch.

Comment: @NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20150318  powered by Lua 5.1.4

Comment: @MarcelStör NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20150318  powered by Lua 5.1.4

Comment: @HabeebRahman Try doing a build from the [NodeMCU Build Service](http://nodemcu-build.com/) (courtesy of Marcel) and see if it works there. 0.9.5 is unfortunately quite old now.

Comment: Your wifi.ap has no getclient method to call. Try a new firmware

Comment: @HabeebRahman Is there any more feedback you need? If not I suggest you consider to accept the answer so that SO can mark this question as closed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your latest comment the solution is simple: you need an up-to-date firmware.

All the pre-built binaries you can download from GitHub are hopelessly outdated and no longer maintained or supported. Do NOT use them.

The current `master` branch is based on Espressif SDK 1.4 and the `dev` branch uses 1.5.1. However, the NodeMCU team does no longer provide recent pre-built binaries. You need to build the firmware yourself. Fortunately that is simple and well documented: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/build/.

The easiest option is to use my [NodeMCU custom build service](http://nodemcu-build.com/) in the cloud.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this several times. I am a big fan of your NodeMCU build service!

Comment: Thanks, glad you find it useful, feel free to donate then ;-)